# Comparing Runtimes - Theoretical to Actual

Tags: comparison, big-o, analysis, mergesort, radix-sort

Firstly, sorry for the long post, but I must be detailed in my explanation here. So here's what I have. I have code that measures the runtime of mergesort and radix sort algorithms for four different sizes of data.

```
Mergesort runtimes:
N = 10;    runtime = 3499 nanoseconds
N = 100;   runtime = 39600 nanoseconds
N = 1000;  runtime = 470199 nanoseconds
N = 10000; runtime = 6227399 nanoseconds

Radixsort runtimes:
N = 10;    runtime = 19200 nanoseconds
N = 100;   runtime = 135099 nanoseconds
N = 1000;  runtime = 1317799 nanoseconds
N = 10000; runtime = 14208600 nanoseconds
```

I have also measured the runtime of a single operation to be roughly 1000 nanoseconds on this machine. This was recommended by the professor as a means help convert theoretical runtimes to something that we can compare to the actual runtimes. For mergesort, I have O(n log(n)) as the runtime, and for radixsort I have O(nk), although I'm not entirely sure what the k represents. He suggested we do the following conversion, so I've done it for each one of the mergesorts. I don't know how to do this for radixsort, as I don't know how to factor in the 'k'. My understanding is that 'k' basically refers to the number of digits, but you can essentially stick with whichever will be larger (N or k), so since my N is always larger than k in the cases I'm working with, I'm just going to consider Radix as O(N). K is limited to six digits at the most, where N begins at 10 at the lowest value.

```
1000ns * theoreticalruntime
For example, 1000ns * 10 log2(10)

Mergesort: 
N = 10;    33219.3 nanoseconds
N = 100;   664385.6 nanoseconds
N = 1000;  9.96578428 * 10^6 nanoseconds
N = 10000; 1.3287712379549449 * 10^8 nanoseconds

Radixsort: (1000ns per operation * N)

N = 10;    10000
N = 100;   100000
N = 1000;  1000000
N = 10000; 10000000
```

So here's where my issue comes in. One, I don't know how to do this calculation for the radixsort theoretical runtime. Two, I don't know exactly how to compare these values using a graph (the requirement).

In class, he was discussing using logs to "normalize" the data. The Y-axis would be N and the X-axis would be time, but he was talking about being able to use logs to change the N values from 10, 100, 1000, and 10000 to where they would show up as N = 1, 2, 3, 4. I have no idea how to do this, and I don't really know what I'd be plotting on the graph. If there's a better place I could be asking this, please point me in that direction. Time runs short.